# Right way to git clone a (laravel) tutorial in homestead

Tags: laravel, git, homestead

I work with homestead on windows for laravel projects. homestead works fine. I dont have a problem with homestead. I have the same folder for my projects on windows and in homestead, `/code/`
I go into the homestaed (`vagrant ssh`). Then i create a new project: `laravel new my-project`. So i have a new project in `/code/my-project`. Synchronized with my windows folder, also `/code/my-project/` All is fine.

But in which folder should I clone a github tutorial? In windows folder, in homestead folder?
Both are not empty (of course). I tried some things. I cloned into Windows folder and at next in homestead `laravel new my-project **--force**`. Or the other way around. First the new project in homestaed, an then an overwriting with gi tutorial in windows folder. Sometimes i got an error server 550 error or No input file specified. But this is not my question. A 100% new project built in homestead runs every time.

I want to know, what is the right / recommended way / sequence. How do you do it?